# wsFederation and ajax all to Web API

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, wif, ws-federation

I have an MVC app, that logs onto a wsFederation STS (I use Identity Server v2 so far).
Everything works fine for that case. I'm using the OWIN authentication middleware for this.

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
 {
      AuthenticationType = WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
      CookieName = ".AspNet.Federation"
 });

 //Trusted Issuer
 parameters.ValidIssuer = "http://identityserver.v2.thinktecture.com/trust/localSTS";

 var options = new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
 {
      MetadataAddress = "https://IdSrv/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml",
      Wtrealm = "urn:relyingparty2",
      IssuerAddress = "https://IdSrv/issue/wsfed",
      TokenValidationParameters = someparameters,
 };

 app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(options);
```

Now, I have another application, which is Web API one, hosted on another domain.

I'd like a user authenticated on the MVC app to be able to make an Ajax call from this app to the web api.
How can the MVC app pass the user to the web api ?

I tried to set the **withCredentials** option on the ajax call, to pass the authentication cookie to the webapi service.

```
var request = {
            url: 'https://localhost:44305/api/test/GetStrings',
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            async: true,
            type: 'GET',
            crossDomain: true,
            success:
            function () {
                alert('ok');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('ko');
            }
        };

        $.ajax(request);
```

Here is the web api controller, configured to enable CORS (which works fine )

```
[EnableCors(origins: "https://localhost,http://localhost", headers: "*", methods: "*", SupportsCredentials = true)]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public IEnumerable<string> GetStrings()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

But when it comes to the webapi config, I don't how to do it.
Using the same config that the web app doesn't work, as the request is redirected to the STS for token issuing.

Any thoughts ? 
Is this the right pattern to use ?

I've also seen on the net that some people would pass the SAML token received from the STS as a bearer token in the authorization header of the ajax call, but it was often said to be not recommended.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same problem -- I can authenticate when I browse to either just fine. But when I use the WebApp to ajax call the WebAPI Service, it redirects to the sts signin. Still stuck

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I didn't figure it out, but from what I remember we used OAuth authorization to help pass a token to Web API